# Выполнение поиска в категории Sphinx php

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Доброе время суток!

Есть такой конфиг Sphinx

```
    source txtcontent :  ru_config
{ 
  sql_query = SELECT `id` as `txt_id`, 1 as index_id, `type_id`,`content_type_id`, `title`, `annonce`, `content` FROM `TxtContent` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `content_type_id` != 14
  sql_attr_uint   = index_id
  sql_attr_uint   = type_id
}
```

Вся таблица индексируется, и хранится в одном большом поисковом индексе. 
Когда речь идет о том что бы найти что то в ней то все работает ОК

Но сегодня встала задача выполнить поиск по категории. Категории описаны в поле type_id и имеют тип int.

Как в php через SphinxAPI выполнить такой поиск?

Стандартный поиск выглядит вот так.

```
$sphinxClient = new SphinxClient();
$sphinxClient->SetServer("127.0.0.1", 3312 );
$sphinxClient->SetLimits( 0, 700,700 );
$sphinxClient->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
$sphinxClient->SetArrayResult( true );
$result = $sphinxClient->Query( $this->query, 'txtcontent provider item');
```

Я пробовал добавлять `$sphinxClient->SetFilter('type_id','1');` чтобы выполнить поиск только там, где type_id = 1, но это не помогло.

Собственно: как мне выполнить поиск по конкретной категории? Вариант найти все и на php выкинуть из результата лишние не рассматривается, (иначе поиск тогда будет затератся существующим лимитом) как это сделать "правильно" через API, не помещая каждую тему в отдельный поисковый индекс?

Comment: А если скормить в SetFilter не строку, а всё-таки массив чисел?

Comment: Я так пробовал уже `$array = array(
    "0" => 1,
 );
 $sphinxClient->SetFilter('index_id',$array)` не чего вообще не поменялось, в результат выдачи попадает другой мусор

Comment: Ох уж эти пхп-массивы. Появляется подозрение, что без воспроизводимого примера с образцом проиндексированных данных помочь будет трудно

Comment: Это косичёк, нужно фильтровать по type_id (уже поправил) type_id принимает разные значения в БД 0 - 10

Comment: Окей, «ошибочка») Ну тогда `$sphinxClient->SetFilter('type_id', array(1))` тоже не работает?

Comment: Да не работает на выходе получается: ` [204]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(31689)
      ["weight"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["attrs"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["index_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type_id"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
    [205]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(31790)
      ["weight"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["attrs"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["index_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["type_id"]=>
        int(2)
      } `  массив как видим тут есть ["type_id"] = 2 когда все значения должны быть только 1

Answer (score 0):

Короче сам решил свою проблему, трабла была в том что 
В поисковых индексах provider item не были проиндексированы с type_id 
в то время как txtcontent был, надо добавить type_id для других индексов и тогда фильтрация пройдет нормально.